# How to verify a signature by Aptos Typescript SDK on backend

Tags: node.js, typescript, signature, aptos

I am developing dApp with Petra wallet & Aptos Typescript SDK.
I could make a signature on frontend, but I don't know how to verify signature on Nodejs backend. I tried to find a way on their documentation & Github, but couldn't get it.

Environments:
Frontend:

```
    "@aptos-labs/ts-sdk": "^1.2.0",
    "@aptos-labs/wallet-adapter-react": "^2.1.2",
```

Backend:

```
"@aptos-labs/ts-sdk": "^1.2.0",
```